# Second portion of inline_keyboard not firing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram

I tried replacing the DY portion with the DDY portion by commenting out it works. It just doesn't work when both code are put together.

What I thought at first is the line below but doesn't make sense if it works for the first time.

```
return editMessageText(chat_id, contents.callback_query.message.message_id,"Reply to this message eg: 5, Earn from MEP MMRC! OR -1, Used on 10/5/23");
```

I thought is a bracketing issue but seems like it might not be?

When selecting DYS1 in telegram it works no issues.

Any idea?

```js
if (text == "/updateoffs") {
  var keyboard = {
    "inline_keyboard": [
      [{
        "text": "DYS1",
        'callback_data': 'dysone'
      }],
      [{
        "text": "DDY",
        'callback_data': 'ddy'
      }],
      [{
        "text": "ACC",
        'callback_data': 'acc'
      }],
      [{
        "text": "4 IN 1",
        'callback_data': 'fourinone'
      }],
      [{
        "text": "PFM IC",
        'callback_data': 'pfmic'
      }],
      [{
        "text": "EXIT IC",
        'callback_data': 'exitic'
      }],
      [{
        "text": "COURSE IC",
        'callback_data': 'courseic'
      }],
      [{
        "text": "CO PA",
        'callback_data': 'copa'
      }]
    ]
  };
  return sendMessage(chat_id, "Select your role to update your current OFFs:", keyboard);
} else if (contents.callback_query) {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl + "/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=" + String(contents.callback_query.id));
  var chat_id = contents.callback_query.message.chat.id;
  var data = contents.callback_query.data;
}
if (data == 'dysone') {
  return editMessageText(chat_id, contents.callback_query.message.message_id, "Reply to this message eg: 5, Earn from MEP MMRC! OR -1, Used on 10/5/23");
}
//!TODO : ALL USER TO UPDATE OFFS BY KEYING IN NUMBER AND REMARKS
if (contents.message.reply_to_message && contents.message.reply_to_message.from.id == 6294332173) {
  var dateNow = new Date;
  var formattedDate = dateNow.getDate() + "/" + (dateNow.getMonth() + 1);
  var item = text.split(",");
  // MAIN SHEET
  var offtracker = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("DY");
  offtracker.getRange(4, 1).setValue([formattedDate]);
  offtracker.getRange(4, 2).setValue(item[0]);
  offtracker.getRange(4, 3).setValue(item[1]);
  //   histracker.appendRow([formattedDate],item[0],item[1]);

  offtracker.insertRows(5, 1);
  var copylist = offtracker.getRange('A4:C4').getValues();
  // then insert data into blank row (5)
  offtracker.getRange('A5:C5').setValues(copylist);
  return sendMessage(chat_id, "OFF TRACKER HAS BEEN UPDATED FOR DYS1!");
}
// else if(contents.callback_query){
//     UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl + "/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=" + String(contents.callback_query.id));
//     var chat_id = contents.callback_query.message.chat.id;
//     var data = contents.callback_query.data;
if (data == 'ddy') {
  return editMessageText(chat_id, contents.callback_query.message.message_id, "Reply to this message eg: 5, Earn from MEP MMRC! OR -1, Used on 10/5/23");
}
//!TODO : ALL USER TO UPDATE OFFS BY KEYING IN NUMBER AND REMARKS
if (contents.message.reply_to_message && contents.message.reply_to_message.from.id == 6294332173) {
  var dateNow = new Date;
  var formattedDate = dateNow.getDate() + "/" + (dateNow.getMonth() + 1);
  var item = text.split(",");
  // MAIN SHEET
  var offtracker = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("DDY");
  offtracker.getRange(4, 1).setValue([formattedDate]);
  offtracker.getRange(4, 2).setValue(item[0]);
  offtracker.getRange(4, 3).setValue(item[1]);
  //   histracker.appendRow([formattedDate],item[0],item[1]);

  offtracker.insertRows(5, 1);
  var copylist2 = offtracker.getRange('A4:C4').getValues();
  // then insert data into blank row (5)
  offtracker.getRange('A5:C5').setValues(copylist2);
  return sendMessage(chat_id, "OFF TRACKER HAS BEEN UPDATED FOR DDY!");
}
}
```

**This below code fires the return text no problem but I'm not sure how to ensure that upon replying to the text respectively it will update the correct google sheet.**

```
    if(data == 'dysone'){
  return editMessageText(chat_id, contents.callback_query.message.message_id,"Reply to this message eg: 5, Earn from MEP MMRC! OR -1, Used on 10/5/23");
}

if(data == 'ddy'){
  return editMessageText(chat_id, contents.callback_query.message.message_id,"DDY");
}

// handle dysone case
if(contents.message.reply_to_message && contents.message.reply_to_message.from.id == 6294332173){
  var dateNow = new Date;
  var formattedDate = dateNow.getDate() + "/" + (dateNow.getMonth() + 1);
  var item = text.split(",");
  // MAIN SHEET
  var offtracker = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("DY");
  offtracker.getRange(4, 1).setValue([formattedDate]);
  offtracker.getRange(4, 2).setValue(item[0]);
  offtracker.getRange(4, 3).setValue(item[1]);
  //   histracker.appendRow([formattedDate],item[0],item[1]);

  offtracker.insertRows(5, 1);
  var copylist = offtracker.getRange('A4:C4').getValues();
  // then insert data into blank row (5)
  offtracker.getRange('A5:C5').setValues(copylist);
  return sendMessage(chat_id, "OFF TRACKER HAS BEEN UPDATED FOR DYS1!");
}

// handle ddy case
if(contents.message.reply_to_message && contents.message.reply_to_message.from.id == 6294332173 && text == "DDY"){
  var dateNow = new Date;
  var formattedDate = dateNow.getDate() + "/" + (dateNow.getMonth() + 1);
  var item = text.split(",");
  // MAIN SHEET
  var offtracker2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("DDY");
  offtracker2.getRange(4, 1).setValue([formattedDate]);
  offtracker2.getRange(4, 2).setValue(item[0]);
  offtracker2.getRange(4, 3).setValue(item[1]);
  //   histracker.appendRow([formattedDate],item[0],item[1]);

  offtracker2.insertRows(5, 1);
  var copylist2 = offtracker2.getRange('A4:C4').getValues();
  // then insert data into blank row (5)
  offtracker2.getRange('A5:C5').setValues(copylist2);
  return sendMessage(chat_id, "OFF TRACKER HAS BEEN UPDATED FOR DDY!");
}
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code there is an issue with the ifs fallthrough and brackets

Comment: I've never seen anything like this before.  How do you access the second property of `keyboard` there is no property name?  There is only `keyboard.inline_keybord` and then a comma.

Comment: Hi. It is accessed by using the callback data.

Comment: I've also changed the code abit to try and pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you really intend for it to be like this?  An array of objects?

```
function test() {
  var keyboard = {
    "inline_keyboard": [
      {
        "text": "DYS1",
        'callback_data': 'dysone'
      },
      {
        "text": "DDY",
        'callback_data': 'ddy'
      },
      {
        "text": "ACC",
        'callback_data': 'acc'
      },
      {
        "text": "4 IN 1",
        'callback_data': 'fourinone'
      },
      {
        "text": "PFM IC",
        'callback_data': 'pfmic'
      },
      {
        "text": "EXIT IC",
        'callback_data': 'exitic'
      },
      {
        "text": "COURSE IC",
        'callback_data': 'courseic'
      },
      {
        "text": "CO PA",
        'callback_data': 'copa'
      }
    ]
  };
  keyboard.inline_keyboard.forEach( key => console.log( key.text) );
}
```

Execution log

```
8:30:07 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:30:07 AM  Info    DYS1
8:30:07 AM  Info    DDY
8:30:07 AM  Info    ACC
8:30:07 AM  Info    4 IN 1
8:30:07 AM  Info    PFM IC
8:30:07 AM  Info    EXIT IC
8:30:07 AM  Info    COURSE IC
8:30:07 AM  Info    CO PA
8:30:07 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Using your original object structure:

```
for( key in keyboard ) console.log(key);
```

Execution log

```
8:33:39 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:33:39 AM  Info    inline_keyboard
8:33:39 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Anyone got any solution?